# Facebook like button not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

My Facebook like button is not working for http://bag.gy. I tried several methods using iframe / html5 but it doesn't increase count.

I have also ensured that the application is already online.

Why is my button not working?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
copy those codes in 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website) do a clear the cache (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)